# if else statement for amount, order, grouping elements sql, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table arrangement:

A post can be a normal "post" or a comment. When this is a comment it contains a value `comment_of` pointing out that this is a comment of an specific post. By other hand this comment can be fixed or not, according if `fixed=1` (fixed)

**PROBLEM**

I want to know if possible to use a `php` like statement to retrieve different amount, order and grouping, among the comments in case it exists a fixed post `fixed=1`.

**table POSTS**

```
     id_post | post | comment_of | fixed    | date
         1      hi          0           0
         2      hello       0           0
         3      comment     1           0
         4      comment     1           0
         5      comment     1           0
         6      comment     1           0
         7      comment     1           0
         8      comment     1           0
         9      comment     1           1 //(fixed - removed or not to show different outputs)
         10     comment     1           0
         11     comment     1           0
         12     comment     1           0
         13     comment     1           0
```

**SQL (MySql)**

```
    SELECT p.*
    FROM table_posts p
        WHERE p.comment_of='1' 

        if(p.fixed==1){
        GROUP BY p.fixed,p.id_post 
        ORDER BY p.fixed DESC,p.date  DESC 
        LIMIT 8
        }else{

        ORDER BY p.date  DESC 
        LIMIT 7
         }
```

**OUTPUT** When fixed comment exists

```
 last 8 results (because it has a fixed post)



     9      comment     1           1 (fixed)
     6      comment     1           0
     7      comment     1           0
     8      comment     1           0
     10     comment     1           0
     11     comment     1           0
     12     comment     1           0
     13     comment     1           0
```

**OUTPUT** In case no fixed comment exists

```
 last 7 results only (because there is no a fixed post)


     6      comment     1           0
     7      comment     1           0
     8      comment     1           0
     10     comment     1           0
     11     comment     1           0
     12     comment     1           0
     13     comment     1           0
```

Comment: Can you give us sample output..

Comment: it was added. thank you

Answer (score 1):

If It's OK to get 8 rows in both cases, then modifying your query will get what you want, I just removed GROUP BY, and ordering by fixed will get the fixed first (if exists) then all the non-fixed ( 0 ) will be ordered by p.date

```
 SELECT p.*
 FROM table_posts p
 WHERE p.comment_of='1' 
 ORDER BY p.fixed DESC, p.date DESC 
 LIMIT 8
```

Comment: pretty interesting

Comment: ok, I tried that out again, the query is pretty nice, but there is this minor detail. It is needed, to have `LIMIT 8` when `fixed=1` and `LIMIT 7` when `fixed=0` How do I make that possible in sql?

Comment: I am not sure if it can be done in the same query as the limit is depending on the existence of one of the resulting rows, but you can do this in your code like fetching the 8 then skipping the last row while displaying, or check the existence of the fixed field in a separate query then according to it make the second query with the right limit